# Go in Peace - why are we sending the Angels away

Tags: song-poetry, malach-angel, shabbat-songs

On Friday night we welcome the angels by singing Shalom Aleichem  the question is why do we tell them:

> צֵאתְכֶם לְשָׁלוֹם מַלְאֲכֵי הַשָּׁלוֹם מַלְאָכֵי עֶלְיוֹן

Essentially sending them away that seems to be a quite ungracious host so why do we do it?

Comment: There are certain Chasidim, such as Bobov that do not say צֵאתְכֶם לְשָׁלוֹם. Perhaps it is for this reason.

Comment: @GershonGold, and some say _tzes'chem uvoachem l'shalom_.

Comment: @GershonGold: and some that say "B'Shivtechem LeShalom" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shalom_Aleichem_(liturgy)#Words

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22431&st=&pgnum=692

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Machatzit Hashekel Siman 262: We don't know when they are going to leave. So we ask them to bless us whenever they decide to leave. Similar to "Blessed are you when coming and blessed when leaving".
2. Avnei Nezer: Shalom Aleichem we say to the Malhachei Hashabat that "came" with us from Shul and Tsetchem Leshalom we say to the Malhacei Hachol (Mundane? weekday?) which were with us during the week. Similar to Ya'akov who had 2 groups of Malachim: One for Eretz Yisrael and the second for Chutz Laharetz.

Comment: +1. Re _Avne Nezer_: [See _Rashi_ on "_olim v'yor'dim bo_".](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8223/showrashi/true#v12) Sounds like we should first say "_tzes'chem_" and then "_boachem_".

Comment: Maybe that in the case of Ya'akov the 2 groups couldn't be together (those from Yisrael couldn't be abroad and vice-versa) but if I understand correctly according to the Avnei Nezer the pair that came with us will stay for the rest of the week so there is no problem in saying it in this order.

Answer (score 8):

From [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/560665/jewish/The-Shalom-Aleichem-Hymn-Explained.htm):

> Although it seems strange to bid farewell to the angels so quickly -- why not invite them to join the Shabbat meal? -- Rabbi Yosef Yitzchak of Lubavitch explained that it is in bad taste to eat while others who are not eating (or in this case, cannot eat) are watching

I also once heard that the Lubavitcher Rebbe said that every second of an angel's existence is very precious and the angel doesn't want to waste time after it has given it's blessing, so we bid it farewell right away.