# Do some abridge the Shabbat evening Kiddush?

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, nuschaot, kiddush, shabbat-songs

I came across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayAMfg9YSPk) from the IDF. The man leading the group leaves off the last verse of Shalom Aleichem.

He also omits sections of the last blessing of Kiddush, specifically

כי הוא יום תחלה

and

כי בנו בחרת ואותנו קדשׂת מכל העמם

What is the reason for this?

Also, can anyone identify the nusach he is canting?  I enjoy the melody and flow very much.

Comment: sholom 3aleicham is not part of qiddush. qiddush is only the blessings. theres no requirement to say anything besides the blessings. and he is most likely using the nosa7 of ari who didnt say those 2 pieces cus of zohar or something wit the 70 crowns. _<edited for tone>_

Comment: I fully realize that shalom aleichem and kiddush are not the same thing... perhaps I should have titled my post a little differently.  In any case, thanks for the info on the origins.

Answer (score 2):

There are those who do not say "tzaischem" because of the idea that you do not want to sent the malachim away. One does not say to a guest as soon as they arrive "When are you leaving". SImilarly, when royalty arrives, it is an insult to ask when they plan to leave. One wants the "Queen" to stay as long as she likes.

Those who say tzaischem learn in a way similar to Yaakov and "Machanaim" of malachim. That is, as he left Eretz Yisroel the malachim of Chutz Laaretz greeted him and the Malachim of Eretz Yisrael left him. When he returned, the Malachim of Eretz Yisrael greeted him and the Malachim of Chutz Laaretz left.

Similarly, the Boachem are the malachim of Shabbos and the Tzeischem are the Malachim of the rest of the week. A person is never left unescorted.

Note that this is why we say Boachem before Tzaischem. If the Malachim of the rest of the week left first, there would be a fraction of time in which one was left alone.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11187

Answer (score 2):

Nusach Sefard leaves out those words when saying Kiddush. Regarding Shalom Aleichem I know that Bobov leaves out that stanza.

Comment: @Aaron, do you have evidence you can share that demonstrates that N"S does not leave out those words, while some Eidot Hamizrach nusach does? If so, you should [edit] that into the answer. If not, then it's your word against C. Ben Yosef's and you might as well write your own unsourced answer. C. Ben Yosef, which did you intend - the Ashkenazi "Nusach Sefard" or a Sefaradi nusach? Can you [edit] this answer to cite a particular siddur? That would improve the quality of the answer a great deal.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Don't have access to the siddur right now. But the Koren Sacks Nusach Sefard siddur has the ki vanu. Whereas the Orot Sephardic Siddur, the Farhi Siddur, etc don't have those verses

Comment: I don't know the exact provenance of these two texts, but the [NS siddur on Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/Siddur,_Sefard.18.5?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) has these phrases in parentheses, while the [EH"M one there](http://www.sefaria.org/Siddur,_Edot_HaMizrach.14.4?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) does not have them. I propose to edit both of these sources into this answer, pending more authoritative sources.

Comment: Until C. Ben Yosef comments, I think it's reasonable to assume that he meant NS when he said it. However, I think it only adds to the answer to have it discuss both NS and EHM, given that relevant evidence is available for both.

Comment: Per Isaac's comments, I'm rolling back the edit pending C. Ben Yosef confirming his intention. Aaron, you are welcome to post another answer or improve this one by _adding_ sourced material, cf Isaac's above comments.

Comment: @DoubleAA If i have time later i'll do it

Comment: Yes I meant Nusach Sefard