# Shalom Aleichem -- "shuvchem" instead of "tzeitchem"?

Tags: nuschaot, communities, shabbat-songs, leil-shabbat

I've heard a setting (by Debbie Friedman) of the song "Shalom Aleichem" that, in the last verse, says "shuvchem" instead of "tzeitchem" ([recording, mixed group of singers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DtG8yv8lzIk)).  A rabbi who knew her told me that the change is so, instead of [asking the malachim to leave as soon as they show up](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44573/472), we instead ask them to return (again, next week).  I was told that this is a chassidic tradition and not original to the composer, but nothing more specific.  I don't have much experience with the chassidic community, but, for what it's worth, I haven't heard this change from Chabad the couple times I've been with them on a Friday night.

Is there a community that does this?  If so, who?  I know of [one family tradition to say "tzes'chem uvoachem l'shalom"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69940/shalom-aleichem-shuvchem-instead-of-tzeitchem#comment200767_69940), so maybe there's a common source?

Comment: Hebrew Google has never seen the phrase Shuvchem Leshalom Malakhei. Are you perhaps thinking of the version with a stanza "BeShivtechem BeShalom" mentioned on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shalom_Aleichem_(liturgy)#Words

Comment: @DoubleAA interesting -- pretty sure I've never heard that verse.  The one I'm talking about is the Debbie Friedman one (mentioned on that WP page), though I've heard it via oral transmission.  (I don't want this question to be about Debbie Friedman in particular; I'm trying to validate or refute a claim about her source and we can't ask her.)

Comment: My family's custom is to say "_tzes'chem uvoachem l'shalom_" ("your leaving and coming for peace") in the last stanza.

Comment: @msh210 I remember Gdoley Israel said this before someone goes on vacation. "Tseschem leShalom uvoachemleshalom".